# SoapServer maps functions incorectly when the wsdl messages have the same part name

Tags: php, soapserver

I'm not sure if this is php bug (bad implementation) or my bug (bad understanding of the SOAP protocol / SoapServer as this is the first time I'm using SoapServer)

I've noticed that if there are two or more operations with the same `wsdl:part` (even if the `wsdl:message` ,  operation and soapAction are different), The `SoapServer` will allways call the first function. In this example, I've two functions `multiply2` and `multiply4` both having `num` (int) as input parameter. earlier today, If I change the part name (service1.wsdl) the functions are mapped correctly.

Although, I don't mind using different names it looks to me like a bug. Am I missing something or should I open a bug ?

This is simple example I've crated:

Very simple php class

```
<?php
class Multi
{
    function multiply2($num) { return ($num * 2 ); }
    function multiply4($num){ return ($num * 4 );  }
}
?>
```

And slightly changed SoapServer (with added logging - [adapted from this post](http://blog.mayflower.de/179-Extending-class-SoapServer-PHP5-for-debugging.html)) but the issue appears when I'm using the plain SoapServer as well:

```
$server = new overloadedSoapServer("service.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'encoding' => SOAP_ENCODED));
$server->setClass("multi");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $server->handle();
}
```

This is the client code:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient('service.wsdl');
$client1 = new SoapClient('service1.wsdl');
echo "<pre>\nFrom service.wsdl:";
echo  "\n".$client->multiply2(10);
echo  "\n".$client->multiply4(10);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>\nFrom service1.wsdl:";
echo  "\n".$client1->multiply2(10);
echo  "\n".$client1->multiply4(10);
echo "</pre>";
```

`service.wsdl` and `service1.wsdl` are basically the same file, with two exception:

1. their endpoint are different (`service.wsdl` points to `http://tests.simsimy.info/web/service.php` and `service1.php` to `http://tests.simsimy.info/web/service1.php` each endpoint uses the appropriate wsdl to load the `SoapServer`)
2. in `service.wsdl` `multiply2Request` and `multiply4Request` have the as part name - `num`, while in `service1.wsdl` the names are different (`num2` and `num4`)

This is the full wsdl of service.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://tests.simsimy.info/web/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="service"
    targetNamespace="http://tests.simsimy.info/web/">
    <wsdl:message name="multiply2Request">
        <wsdl:part name="num" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="multiply2Response">
        <wsdl:part name="res" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="multiply4Request">
        <wsdl:part name="num" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="multiply4Response">
        <wsdl:part name="res" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="dd">
        <wsdl:operation name="multiply2">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:multiply2Request"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:multiply2Response"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="multiply4">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:multiply4Request"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:multiply4Response"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="serviceSOAP" type="tns:dd">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="multiply2">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tests.simsimy.info/web/multiply2" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="multiply4">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tests.simsimy.info/web/multiply4" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="multiply_service">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:serviceSOAP" name="serviceSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://tests.simsimy.info/web/service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The changed part in `service1.wsdl` :

```
<wsdl:message name="multiply2Request">
        <wsdl:part name="num2" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="multiply2Response">
        <wsdl:part name="res" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="multiply4Request">
        <wsdl:part name="num4" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="multiply4Response">
        <wsdl:part name="res" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
```

When I run the client code I get the following ouput:

```
From service.wsdl:
20
20

From service1.wsdl:
20
40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the binding style in your wsdl from 'document' to 'rpc'.

First I thought it is a cache problem as your posted server code above does not contains the ini_set() to disabled the cache. But is isn't a cache problem.

Having traced http traffic. Client seems working porperly it is a SoapServer problem. (Like you mentioned).. Further investigating ...

A bug report has already been [filed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49169) - although it is currently unclear if it is a bug.

Workarounds are mentioned in the bug report too. You can change the binding style to rpc if this is ok for you:

Change

```
<soap:binding style="document"
```

to

```
<soap:binding style="rpc"
```

This workaround works for me. You will find a very interesting article on how binding styles work [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/). This may help you to decide whether rpc binding style is ok for you or not.

Comment: it isn't cache use, bit the server and the client have the `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled` set to 0 and there is no cache in the temp folder.

Comment: Ok, in my tests this lead to a problem like yours.